# Weird behavior dereferencing std::list iterator

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator, stdarray

I am running into strange behavior when using `std::list<std::array<T>>::iterator`.

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct S {
    uint64_t x;    
};

#define N 10000

typedef array<S, N> block;
typedef list<block>::iterator it;

int main() {
    list<block> l;
    l.emplace_back();
    block& b = l.front();
    it i = l.begin();
    l.emplace_back();
    std::cout << i->data() << " " << b.data() << "\n";
    b = *(++i);
    std::cout << i->data() << " " << b.data() << "\n";
}
```

It gives me the following output:

```
0x55c2b63cbec0 0x55c2b63cbec0
0x55c2b63df760 0x55c2b63cbec0
```

When accessing the `.data()` through the iterator, it correctly points to the next element. However, dereferencing the incremented iterator gives me a reference to the same old element. I have been scratching my head over this for some hours now. Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding how iterators work?

When I try the same code but with just `list<int>`, it works as expected.

```
    list<int> l;
    l.emplace_back(0);
    int& b = l.front();
    list<int>::iterator i = l.begin();
    l.emplace_back(1);
    std::cout << *i << " " << b << "\n";
    b = *(++i);
    std::cout << *i << " " << b << "\n";
```

Produces the expected output:

```
0 0
1 1
```

Comment: You can't re-point references; you're doing a copy-assignment of the referenced array, and assigning to a `std::array` just copies its elements; it doesn't change where `data()` points.

Comment: Yep, realized that very quickly after seeing the answer below. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Unrelated: For `uint64_t` you need `#include<cstdint>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable b is declared as a reference

```
block& b = l.front();
```

So in this statement

```
b = *(++i);
```

the second element of the list is assigned to the first element of the list.

So in this statement

```
std::cout << i->data() << " " << b.data() << "\n";
```

there are outputted values of returned by the member function data for the second element of the list and the first element of the list.

In the second example there is returned the same integer value that was assigned to the first element of the list.

You could get in the first program a similar result as in the second program if instead of using the member function data you would try to output values of arrays (provided that they are initialized for visibility).

Comment: That was it! Thanks. Going to go and sulk for a while.